# Pagination not give another posts

Tags: posts, pagination, blog

i make it a custom page blog with 4 post per page but when i want to change the page, i get same posts from the first page. This is how is look my code
`

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' =>4, 'post_type' => 'post' , 'order'=> 'DESC',  'orderby' => 'post_date', 'paged' => $paged,'post_status' => 'publish');
$postslist = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<div class="container-of-dp">
<?php
if ( $postslist->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $postslist->have_posts() ) : $postslist->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="article-div">
             <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url();?>"/>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> </a><br />
            <small><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> by <?php the_author(); ?></small>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?><br />
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    
    </div>
    <div class="navigation-blog">
        <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link( '&laquo; Previous ' ); ?></div>
        <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link( 'Next  &raquo;', $postslist->max_num_pages ); ?></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Try removing `offset` property. If this code runs on `front-page.php` then `get_query_var('paged')` should be `get_query_var('page')`.

Comment: @Buttered_Toast It's manifest the same

Comment: Where is this code located, at what file? does the url change with `/page/2`?

Comment: Url is changing. File is a template

Comment: Could you update your code to reflect the new changes?. I just tested your code on my local env and it works great, if you remove `'offset' => 0`

Comment: Updated, here is the link you can test it live https://digitalpoint.ro/blog/

Comment: You also changed `get_query_var('page')`, this should be `get_query_var('paged')`

Comment: The first one or the second one

Comment: See my first comment. Both should be changed.

Comment: Done,but the page is incremente right,but still posts not changing

Comment: Lets [chat here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130278/pagination-not-give-another-posts)

Comment: @Buttered_Toast sorry but i don't have 15 rep

Comment: OK, try creating a clean template and add the code there, if it works in the new created template then there is something else if the template that creates the problem. The code is correct so there should be no issues. Without access to your code its difficult to say what causes this issue.

Comment: We can chat to another platform like discord,i don't know if its politicaly correct?